# Can I use dynamic criterias that follows the range with countif in Excel?

Tags: excel-formula, countif

I want to count number of cells in a range which date is more than one month behind today's date.

I tried this:

```
=COUNTIF(D6:D10, "<" & D6-EDATE(D6,1)+TODAY())
```

The problem is that this code uses the the same criteria with the value of D6 for the whole range. I want it to use D7 in criteria for range D7, D8 for D8 etc.

Hope anyone can understand my problem and help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is always good to provide some sample data.

Comment: `=COUNTIF(D6:D10, "<" & EDATE(TODAY(),-1))`

Comment: @ScottCraner, I never thought of using a negative number in the EDATE-function. Thanks!